# Connect by prior in Java and HQL

Tags: java, hql

How can i use connect by prior in my HIBERNATE QUERY (HQL) query?
query contains  START WITH ----- CONNECT BY ----------- PRIOR

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. Use

```
session.createNativeQUery
```

Answer (score -1):

As said it is impossible, so I had another way around with
"Session.createSQLQuery" by just using simple sql query.